# Interpolating z Values (height) from TIN (Raster) to line (vector) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, interpolation, tin

I have a raster (TIN) and I want to interpolate the heights (z-Values) to a line Shape. Everything that I find is interpolation between some points and making a raster. For example, Raster creation tools of SAGA or IDW or TIN interpolation, they all get a vector layer as an input file and make a Raster out of the values from attribute table.

Any idea?

Comment: I think you're looking for a profile tool

Comment: Yes, it could do also what I need. Is the name of plugin "Profile tool"?

Comment: [Drape](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissetzfromraster) is not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a linestrings layer with Z dimension, use the Drape (set Z value from raster) algorithm to assign the Z dimension from the raster to each vertice of the linestrings.

But there is not an interpolation there, the vertice will get the Z value of the pixel in wich it belongs.

Then, you can densify the lines to get other vertices with their Z dimension interpolated for each segment. But I don't know if that is what you want.

If you want to extract contours from the raster, that can be done with the Contour algorithm.